# Incomplete rotation from imported FBX

Tags: bones, .fbx, quaternion

I'm trying to import an fbx to Blender, with one simple animation (exported from Moho).

When I export it from Moho, I can open it in tools such as FBX Converter and Windows 3D viewer, and the animation is correct:[image: correct rotation]

But then, when I import it to Blender, the animation goes like this (incomplete):[image: incorrect rotation]

I noticed that the rotation becomes incorrect when I export the rotation with more than 120º or so. I think that this must be related to gimbal lock, but I don't know how to fix it.

In Moho, I'm doing the whole rotation in one single keyframe rotating 360 degrees. When I do it in two keyframes with 180 degrees each to complete the whole turn, it will be correct in Blender.
I think I could fix it manually, but I don't want to have this work for all animations I would create.